# using mulit thread with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I am working on a project using Spring Boot.
If I create a class like this the thread doesn't work.
DAO works sequentially.
example (1.2.3.4.5.....100)

```
Service class
    for(int i = 1; i <= 30; j++) {
      threadServiceMethod(i);
    }

ThreadService class
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<DTO>> threadServiceMethod(int i) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(DAO method);
    }

DAO class
    public List<Dto> daoMethod() {
        //select code
    }
```

But It works if @Async is connected to daoMethod
However, the result value that the client receives is null.

```
ThreadService class
    public CompletableFuture<List<DTO>> threadServiceMethod(int i) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(DAO method);
    }

DAO class

    @Async
    public List<Dto> daoMethod() {
        //select code
    }
```

If @async is used for threadmethod and dao, logs are output sequentially.
Why does it work like this??
help me :(